# Is there a hard keyboard case for the iPad keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Is there a hard case for the Apple wireless keyboard for the iPad?

The case is to make the keyboard safe to transport, like in a backpack or something.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any *hard* cases, but Waterfield/SFBags makes some [nice soft cases](http://www.sfbags.com/products/keyboard-cases/keyboard-cases.php) you can use for transporting your Apple Bluetooth Keyboard:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sfbags.com](http://www.sfbags.com/images/prodpage_keyboardtravelcase.jpg))</sub>   [image]
<sub>(source: [sfbags.com](http://www.sfbags.com/images/prodpage_keyboard_sleeve.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I really like the [inCase Origami Workstation](http://goincase.com/products/detail/origami-workstation-cl57934) because in addition to protecting the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard, it unfolds to support the iPad in a comfortable typing position.

Andy Ihnatko included it in [*A spring selection of iPad-friendly accessories worth a look*](http://www.suntimes.com/technology/ihnatko/5262350-452/a-spring-selection-of-ipad-friendly-accessories-worth-a-look.html)

Apologies for the commerce link above. The link is to the manufacturer's site and they don't separate *product* from *store*. The Origami is widely available from a number of sources—I picked mine up at a local Apple Store—and no endorsement of inCase as the retail outlet is implied.