# On the lookout for an iPad 2 case that integrates a keyboard but doesn't block the camera

Tags: keyboard, ipad, hardware-recommendation, case

I currently have an iPad 2 with a Smart Cover. I am looking for a keyboard that can be attached to the device so that I will always have the keyboard with me in a convenient manner. Some requirement for the ideal keyboard:

- Compatible with the Smart Cover
- Keys aren't exposed when the keyboard is "stashed away".
- Leaves a hole for the rear camera.

I really like the [Logitech® Fold-Up Keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/keyboards/keyboard/devices/fold-up-keyboard-ipad); however, it blocks the camera. Depending on the hardware inside, I may be able to drill a hole in the back of the shell, but it would only help for those times that I have the keyboard out. I probably won't ever want the keyboard out while taking a picture with the rear camera. Which keyboards (if any besides the given one) meet all or most of the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know that a case meeting all of your criteria exists. It might be time to dig out the dremel tool and DIY.

My iPad keyboard solution is to use an [inCase Origami Workstation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/40462/11791) and the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard. I don't carry the keyboard most of the time, but it does go into my bag if I think I'm going to be in a fixed location and do extended writing and when I  travel—where it generally stays in my hotel room for use at the desk. This doesn't meet your strict criteria, but it may be an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Zagg wireless keyboard/case when I bought my iPad2.  It doesn't cover the camera lens when installed.